# 1080px height publishing with address bar

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I saw the design of size 1920x1080 and I am publishing it. Sometimes, even when working in a right size, the address bar causes scrolling beyond 1080 in height. In this case, do I have to modify the design? I wonder how other people work.

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div
      style={{ width: "1920px", height: "1080px", backgroundColor: "black" }}
    />
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div
      style={{ width: "1920px", height: "100vh", backgroundColor: "black",overflow:"hidden" }}
    />
  );
};

export default App;
```